# iPhone - How to convert aiff audio files into aac?

Tags: iphone, audio, aac, m4a

I'm developing an iphone app that records audio, right now it records aiff files, I need to convert these files to aac... any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Apple provides iOS sample code for the ExtAudioFile API that handles conversion:  [iPhoneExtAudioFileConvertTest](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/iPhoneExtAudioFileConvertTest/Introduction/Intro.html)

Answer (score 0):

There's also a open-source library for aac conversion based on Apple's sample code that's a bit easier to use (using Objective-C):

https://github.com/michaeltyson/TPAACAudioConverter

Here's a blog entry by the author describing the project, along with questions and answers:

http://atastypixel.com/blog/easy-aac-compressed-audio-conversion-on-ios/